# Invertibility of Mixing Matrix $M$ in $A=CMR$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-rank

I'm interested in solving the following problem from Strang's Linear Algebra and Learning from Data:

> If $C$ and $R$ contain bases for the column space and row space of $A$, why does $A=CMR$ for some square invertible matrix $M$?

In this context $A$ is an arbitary rectangular $m \times n$ matrix, $C$ is $m \times r$ and $R$ is $r \times n$. As $C^TC$ and $RR^T$ are both invertible, one finds that
$$M=(C^TC)^{-1} C^TAR^T(RR^T)^{-1}. $$
This $M$ is evidently $r \times r$, and I could get invertibility by showing that $C^TAR^T$ is invertible. However, I couldn't show that. The results of rank of a product I'm aware of don't hold in this case. Also the implication $C^TAR^T x=0 \implies x=0$ proved too difficult for me.

Any advice on proving $M$ is invertible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Notation

For clarity, let's define $A = CR$ and $A = CMR^*$ to disambiguate the $R$'s.

#### Proof by using a property of ranks

[A property of ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) states $rank(AB) \le min(rank(A),rank(B))$.

In our case,

$$
\begin{align}
rank(MR^*) &\le min(rank(M),rank(R^*)) \\
rank(R) &\le min(rank(M),rank(R^*)) \\
r &\le min(rank(M),r) \\
\end{align}
$$

because

- $R*$, like $R$, has $r$ independent rows, by construction
- $M$ is $r \times r$
- $rank(M) = r$ is the only value that fits the inequality above

Since $M$ is **full-rank**, it is invertible.